# Rails routing /forum/[category_id]/[topic_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I would like to create nested routes for my forum, where a topic belongs to a category.

I'm **not liking** the default nested routes

```
resources :forum_category do
  resources :forum_topic
end
```

which would give me something like `/forum_category/[forum_category_id]/forum_topic/[forum_topic_id]`

---

**What I want:**

I'm looking to create the following rules (leaving out POST, PATCH, PUT routes)

```
/forum                                      => forum_topic#index
/forum/new                                  => forum_topic#new
/forum/[forum_category_id]                  => forum_topic#index
/forum/[forum_category_id]/[forum_topic_id] => forum_topic#show
```

So `/forum` is my index, `forum/open-mic` is my index limited to category with seo slug `open mic` and finally `/forum/open-mic/lets-talk-about-fun` would be my forum topic `lets-talk-about-fun` which is categorized under `open-mic`.

Is there any solution for this build into Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for GET requests you can do this:

```
get '/forum', to: "forum_topic#index", as: :forum_topics
get '/forum/new', to: "forum_topics#new", as: :new_forum_topic
get '/forum/:forum_category_id', to: "forum_topics#show", as: :forum_topic_category
get '/forum/:forum_category_id/:forum_topic_id', to: "forum_topic#show_topic", as: :show_forum_topic_category
```

You could map the last two to the same controller action and redirect based on params, but I'd recommend setting up two separate actions for readability.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this for customize routes:

```
match "<your-url>", to:"<controller>#<action>", as: "<path-name>", via: :<your method-like GET,POST,DELETE>
```

for example to GET:

```
match "forum_category/:forum_category_id/forum_topic/:forum_topic_id", to: "forum_topic#show", as: "show_topic", via: :get
```

and for POST:

```
match "forum_category/:forum_category_id/forum_topic", to: "forum_topic#update", as: "update_topic", via: :post
```

in your controller you have this params:
    `param[:forum_category_id]` and `param[:forum_topic_id]`